Does it matter what's the driver use spring boot with r2dbc
Does it matter what's the driver use spring boot 2.7.* with r2dbc?
The project which has this FailoverConnectionFactoryProvider
https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/issues/120
Can I just delete FailoverConnectionFactoryProvider and add dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Is it just about driver or spring boot will have some setting and will not work with it?
